# Unable to catch events from iPad wireless keyboard

Tags: jquery, ipad, keyboard, keyboard-events

I wanted to use the arrow keys for my iPad App, so I am connecting the wireless keyboard and thought that things will work.

The thing is I am not getting any event call (specifically `keyDown`) on pressing those keys which the iPad doesn't have - like arrow keys.
Arrows and other keys are working for other apps , so this might be JS issue ?

Am I missing something? Does the keyboard connection require something?

Comment: I don't see the problem with the question. He's trying to catch keyboard events from an external keyboard on an iPad. It's a software development question, not a hardware one.

Comment: Have you tried using keypress?

Comment: silly to read .tough to solve .

Comment: Yes i tried , they are working on Safari ( with the mac keyboard attached obv ) but not for the mobile Safari or iPad App.